# How can I make the mousePressed and mouseDoubleClicked events mutually exclusive?

Tags: c++, qt

Hey guys ... Well I'm experiencing this silly problem that whenever I perform a double click event, two mousePressed events are also triggered, meaning that mousePressed event code is also executed twice for no reason .. How can I configure the event such that first the clicks are checked for doubleClick event, and only if this is NOT true, they move on to mousePressed events .. ? Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Before you spend too much time trying to figure this out, consider what Raymond Chen has said about the ["Logical consequences of the way Windows converts single-clicks into double-clicks"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041015-00/?p=37553). The techniques he talks about should be easily adaptable to Qt.  But also the UI consequences of the "dubious design of having the double-click action be unrelated to the single-click action" - you may be trying to do something that will be confusing to your users (on the other hand - you might trying to prevent something from confusing your users).

Also, the related article, ["Why doesn't double-right-click bring up the Properties dialog?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100308-00/?p=14693) might be of interest.

Comment: +1.  And if you find that single clicking does something "time consuming", then don't try to avoid getting the message twice.  Just find some other state in your system you can test for if the time consuming thing has already been done, then don't do it again when you get the second message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you mean for the same widget. The quick and dirty way would be to move the mouse press code into a private method, have the mouse press event set a timer to go off **after** the expire timer for a possible double click. In the double click code be sure to turn off the timer if it gets called. This will prevent the mouse press event from running twice. In the timer code, have it call the private method.